# How can I break up a list in prolog, given a pivot?

Tags: arrays, split, prolog, infinite-loop, break

I'm working on a small project to lean prolog. What I'm trying to do right now is, given a sentence, return a list of words. So, I'm taking in a character array, e.g. "highs and lows", and trying to split it up into "highs" "and" "lows". I'm using a character array because I want to play with the words themselves, and I don't think strings work for that.

Here's my code.

```
get_first_word([], _, []):-
  !.
get_first_word(X, Pivot, Input):-
  append(X, [Pivot|_], Input),
  !.

split_at([],_).
split_at(Input, Pivot):-
  get_first_word(X, Pivot, Input),
  writef(X),
  append(X, Y, Input),
  split_at(Y, Pivot).
```

The problem I'm getting is that this turns into an infinite loop. Eventually it'll pass itself empty input, and my base case isn't well-written enough to handle this. How do I fix this?

Comment: In the case you plan on using SWI-Prolog, you might want to use atoms for representing words and sentences. You can then make use of the built-ins for analyzing and constructing atoms ( http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,'4.21',swi('/doc/Manual/manipatom.html')) ), for example `atomic_list_concat/3`, which basically does exactly what you describe for atoms.

Comment: I'm trying to make a simple translation script, and I'll need to play with the individual words and word parts a lot. Am I able to "assemble" strings with SWIProlog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `get_first_word` misses an argument: it should 'return' both the word and the rest, accounting for the possibility that Pivot doesn't appear in input.

I've also moved arguments to follow the conventional 'input at begin, output at end'.

```
get_first_word(Input, Pivot, Word, Rest):-
  append(Word, [Pivot|Rest], Input), !.
get_first_word(Input, _Pivot, Input, []).

split_at([], _).
split_at(Input, Pivot):-
  get_first_word(Input, Pivot, W, Rest),
  writef(W),nl,
  split_at(Rest, Pivot).
```

test:

```
?- split_at("highs and lows", 0' ).
highs
and
lows
true .
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use SWI-Prolog, it is worth considering using atoms to represent sentences, words, parts of words and so on. As you can see [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.21%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipatom.html%27%29%29), you problem becomes (if your sentence is an atom):

```
?- atomic_list_concat(Ws, ' ', 'highs and lows').
Ws = [highs, and, lows].
```

There are further useful predicates, for example `atom_concat/3` (we can say it is `append/3` for atoms), or `sub_atom/5` which can be useful in multiple ways.

As a side note, SWI-Prolog has no artificial limit on the length of atoms and actually recommends using atoms instead of strings or character code lists.

Answer (score 1):

When describing lists (in this case: lists of character codes, which is what your strings are), always also consider using DCGs. For example:

```
string_pivot_tokens(Cs, P, Ts) :- phrase(tokens(Cs, P, []), Ts).

tokens([], _, Ts)     --> token(Ts).
tokens([C|Cs], P, Ts) -->
        (   { C == P } -> token(Ts), tokens(Cs, P, [])
        ;   tokens(Cs, P, [C|Ts])
        ).

token([])     --> [].
token([T|Ts]) --> { reverse([T|Ts], Token) }, [Token].
```

Example:

```
?- string_pivot_tokens("highs and lows", 0' , Ts), maplist(atom_codes, As, Ts).
Ts = [[104, 105, 103, 104, 115], [97, 110, 100], [108, 111, 119, 115]],
As = [highs, and, lows] ;
false.
```